# Setting up different git roots for different modules in same project - Intellij IDEA

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

How can I setup git in Intellij to have different git repositories for each module in 1 project.

I have an API I am maintaining and my fork of an Open Source project as 2 different modules in 1 intellij project.  I would like each module to push/pull with a different git repository.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`File` | `Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac) | `Version Control` dialog allows to map different directories to a version control, so just make several mappings instead of one, map each module root to Git.

Comment: When i try to update the module, it tries to update the project and fails. How can i tell it to only update that particular module?

Answer (score 8):

It is much easier to edit the vcs.xml directly.

```
[project folder]/.idea/vcs.xml
```

The entries are like:

```
<mapping directory="$USER_HOME$/project_folder_a" vcs="Git" />
<mapping directory="$USER_HOME$/project_folder_b" vcs="Git" />
```

Comment: Also which file is to add a module directly?

Comment: This works great. The `push` window shows both repos and you can choose which one to push.

Answer (score 3):

On a mac it's located at Intellij Idea-> Preferences -> Version Control