# IntelliJ Project with multiple GitHub roots for modules

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I've been using Git's command line to push my code to GitHub, but lately I figured it'd be better to use the built in VCS that IntelliJ offers. How can I set up my project so that each module maps to a different Github project?

I tried following this question too [Setting up different git roots for different modules in same project - Intellij IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725566/setting-up-different-git-roots-for-different-modules-in-same-project-intellij) but it looks like it's setting it up with git directly, and not GitHub.

What I tried was to "check out from GitHub", but when it asked me to create a new project, I declined, because I want to set it up as a module and not a new project.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far you've done everything correctly, including declining the creation of a new project. The only thing you have to do now, is create a new module out of the checked out source:

`File` > `Import Module` > Select your checked out folder > `Create module from existing sources` > `Finish`

Comment: If I import the module, then will it have all of the version control options?

Comment: Yes. Each module has its own version control root. So you can commit changes to module1, without changing module2.